# How I can apply a patch to specific files depending the installed version of a composer dependency

Tags: php, composer-php

In my case I want once I do:

```
composer install
```

After the dependencies being downloaded to replace some files in vendor based upon a json names hotpatch.json and will have theese entries:

```
{
  "my_dependency":{
     "v1.1":[
          {
            "original":"./vendor/my_dependency/app/Myclass.php"
            "replacement":"./hotpatch/my_dependency/app/v1/Myclass.php"
          }
     ]
  }
}
```

Or in case a php version and extention version is specific:

```
{
  "my_dependency":{
     "v1.1":[
          {
            "original":"./vendor/my_dependency/app/Myclass.php"
            "replacement":[
                {                 
                  php_version: "7.4",
                  ext-curl: "1.2",
                  file:"./hotpatch/my_dependency/app/v1/Myclass.php"
               }
            ]
          }
     ]
  }
}
```

The idea is because legacy applications have strict rules upon dependencies and I may not have the option to decide where the app will run I want to ensure that a specific version of a dependency is appropriately patched. At the same time I want to keep the best practices as well.

Also I want to ensure that all my dependencies are approriately patched whilst keep a dump-to-use approach for inexperienced developers as well. Using a automated copy-pasta approach seem good enough especially in a time-restricted environment where each second of development hour counts.

Is there an tool that allows me to do this? I mean having the project as is and testing it on the fly is time saving upon manhours.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches?